# How to boot Ubuntu 22.04.1 as read-only?

Tags: grub2, filesystem, grub-efi

Trying to figure out how to boot Ubuntu 22.04.1 installed to internal SSD as read-only (similar to Tails).

Comment: Depending on what you wish to do, recovery mode might be your choice; just do not run the `fsck` option in the last menu (if I remember correctly). If that doesn't do what you wish; you will likely need to tell more about what you intentend to do.

Comment: Thanks @user535733… looks like `overlayroot` is what I was looking for.